# How do I turn \n into a <br> tag when pulling my JSON data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

My JSON output currently looks like this:

```
"description":"MUSIC VIDEO - 7:13\n\nCREDITS\n\nLabel: Black Pain Records\nProduction Company: Idyll Films
```

I have this bit of jQuery to fetch and input as text:

```
$.getJSON("http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/"+strip2+"&callback=?",
                function(json){
                $('.creditText').text(json.description);
            });
```

strip2 is my vimeo id. Currently the output is all one line, I would like where the \n is to be converted into 
 tags, is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace the line `$('.creditText').text(json.description);` with:

```
$('.creditText').html(json.description.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>");
```

Please note that you need to change `text()` to `html()` so the `<br/>` elements will be inserted as HTML and shown on the page.

See the **[code](http://jsbin.com/iduyoc/4/edit)**.

Comment: can we use prepend or append instead of html? these two functions does the same thing

Answer (score 7):

you could do

```
json.description.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')
```

Comment: You need a regular expression, otherwise only the first occurrence will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

use replace function of java-script for this...

```
$.getJSON("http://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/"+strip2+"&callback=?",
                function(json){
                $('.creditText').text(json.description.replace('\n','<br>'));
            });
```